# Trying to import comma-separated data in R

Tags: r

I would like to read some comma-seperated data in to R for plotting. However, it is not possible to copy paste this data and do `data = c(...)`. So I tried putting everything in a .txt and use `read.table("path_to_file", header = F, sep = ",")` howver, this generated the error:

```
Warning message:
In read.table("tmp.txt",  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'tmp.txt'
```

Data:

```
7,9,8,5,5,5,6,9,9,5,8,6,6,9,7,8,5,7,5,7,7,8,7,5,5,8,7,9,4,4,6,9,7,9,8,7,7,7,8,7,7,6,8,6,7,8,8,8,7,7,7,9,-25,9,7,8,9,8,7,6,7,8,9,6,6,7,5,8,5,6,7,8,7,7,7,9,7,7,7,7,6,7,8,2,7,7,7,5,8,5,6,7,7,8,8,7,5,9,2,-29,8,9,7,7,8,7,6,9,8,6,6,9,6,8,7,9,8,6,7,6,7,8,8,8,9,8,8,9,7,8,7,6,9,8,6,8,8,9,9,-26,8,7,8,9,9,5,9,7,9,8,6,4,7,7,8,5,8,9,8,5,9,8,8,8,8,8,8,5,8,4,9,7,9,8,7,9,8,6,8,8,7,9,9,7,7,8,9,-19,8,8,5,7,4,7,8,6,7,7,8,5,7,8,9,8,7,8,-21,5,4,5,7,4,7,7,8,3,7,8,6,5,7,3,8,7,5,8,8,9,8,5,9,8,8,8,8,8,5,6,7,8,8,7,6,7,6,8,7,6,7,8,-20,9,9,5,9,8,8,7,8,7,7,8,7,7,9,8,7,8,9,5,-24,9,8,9,6,7,8,8,8,9,9,6,6,7,8,7,7,-24,9,8,-20,8,5,8,8,9,-21,7,9,8,6,7,6,9,6,9,8,8,9,-21,8,8,9,7,8,6,6,-25,9,6,7,8,6,8,9,9,8,8,8,9,7,9,9,7,7,6,7,8,7,8,6,8,8,9,8,8,7,8,6,7,8,-21,9,8,-23,6,7,9,9,7,6,7,6,-24,7,9,8,9,9,9,7,7,7,9,8,8,8,9,8,8,9,9,9,8,7,7,8,9,9,9,8,8,8,-19,9,8,7,-20,6,7,7,8,6,9,-19,7,8,6,6,6,7,6,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,-24,8,9,8,7,-23,9,8,7,8,8,9,9,8,9,8,8,9,8,8,7,8,8,9,8,-24,8,8,7,8,7,-17,8,9,8,9,-24,8,9,6,-19,9,7,7,9,8,7,9,7,-20,8,6,8,9,-17,7,-18,9,7,6,9,8,9,7,7,9,7,8,9,8,8,9,7,8,7,7,9,8,9,-20,8,9,9,7,9,8,9,9,9,7,7,8,9,8,9,7,7,8,9,8,8,9,8,8,7,7,6,-22,9,9,8,8,8,9,9,8,8,8,7,9,8,7,9,9,8,6,9,8,7,8,9,-21,-20,-19,-16,-19,-22,8,8,8,-20,8,8,8,7,7,7,8,8,9,8,9,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,-18,5,4,6,8,9,5,-21,8,-20,9,9,9,8,8,9,9,8,8,9,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,8,9,9,8,9,7,7,7,9,-16,8,9,8,9,9,8,8,9,8,9,7,8,9,9,8,9,9,9,8,9,8,8,8,8,9,8,8,9,7,9,9,7,-25,-19,-19,9,9,-21,7,-19,8,7,8,9,-17,8,7,9,8,8,7,9,9,9,7,7,9,9,8,9,-18,8,9,8,8,9,-20,-18,-20,9,-20,-18,9,8,7,-21,9,9,8,9,6,-20,9,9,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,7,8,9,8,9,9,-17,9,8,-18,-20,9,8,9,7,9,7,-15,-17,-17,-19,-15,9,-19,-16,9,9,9,9,9,9,-14,9,9,9,8,9,9,9,7,-15,8,9,8,9,9,-17,8,9,9,9,8,-19,-16,9,8,-17,9,9,8,9,9,8,9,9,9,8,-15,-15,9,9,8,9,8,-14,-15,9,-17,9,9,8,9,9,-18,8,-16,-16,-17,9,8,9,-15,9,9,7,8,9,8,9,9,7,8,9,8,-15,9,9,9,9,7,8,9,9,9,9,-15,-15,7,-16,8,-16,-15,9,-17,-15,9,-19,9,-14,9,-14,-14,-18,-16,9,8,-15,-18,9,-17,-17,9,9,9,9,9,-15,-16,8,8,9,9,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,-16,9,9,9,9,8,-15,-19,-14,-14,-15,-15,-11,-16,9,-14,7,7,-16,9,7,9,9,9,9,8,-11,-15,9,9,9,9,-14,-15,-15,-13,9,-12,-16,-12,9,-15,-15,-14,-15,-13,9,-15,-14,9,-14,-12,-15,-11,-14,-12,9,-12,9,-14,9,9,9,-13,8,-12,9,-11,9,-12,9,-10,-11,-10,-13,9,-13,-13,9,-11,-15,-11,-10,9,-12,-13,-11,-15,-10,-11,-10,-12,9,9,-11,-10,9,-11,-11,9,9,-14,-10,-10,-12,-11,9,9,-10,-11,9,9,9,-11,-10,-12,-10,9,9,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,9,-10,-10,-10,8,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,9,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,9,9,9,-10,-12,-10,-11,-10,-12,-12,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,9,-11,-14,-12,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-12,-11,-10,-12,-11,-10,-10,-12,-11,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-12,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-12,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-11,9,-10,-11,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,9,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,9,-10,9,9,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,9,9,8,-10,-10,-11,-12,-11,-12,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-12,-10,9,-11,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,9,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-12,-12,-10,-12,-14,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-12,-12,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,9,9,9,-10,-11,9,-11,-10,8,-10,-10,-11,9,-10,9,-11,-10,-11,-10,9,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-11,-11,-12,-10,-10,9,9,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,9,-10,9,9,-10,-10,9,9,-10,9,-11,9,-10,-10,9,-10,8,-10,-10,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,9,-10,9,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-11,-10,9,-10,-10,9,-11,9,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,9,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,9,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,9,9,-10,-11,-10,9,-11,-11,9,-10,-12,-12,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-11,9,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-13,-11,-11,-12,-10,-12,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-13,-10,-11,-10,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,9,-10,9,9,-10,-11,-11,-12,-10,-10,9,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,9,9,-10,-10,-10,9,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-12,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-11,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-12,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-11,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-12,-11,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-11,-11,-12,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-14,-10,-10,-11,-11,-13,-11,-10,-10,-11,-13,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-75,-11,-10,-10,-11,-68,-53,-59,-66,0,-69,-72,-73,1,3,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-3,-3,-3,-73,-73,-71,-74,-71,-72,-74,-72,-72,-70,-71,-74,-71,-71,-71,-72,-71,-70,-70,-71,-71,-72,-71,-72,-71,-71,-72,-72,-71,-70,-70,-71,-70,-73,-71,-71,-73,-73,-73,-72,-71,-70,-71,-72,-73,-73,-70,-70,-71,-70,-68,-9,-73,-69,-70,-9,-69,-69,-71,-72,-73,-73,-72,-73,-72,-72,-73,-73,-72,-73,-71,-70,-71,-71,-74,-71,-71,-72,-74,-74,-72,-71,-71,-72,-72,-72,-72,-72,-71,-72,-72,-72,-72,-73,-74,-72,-71,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-1,-3,-3,-3,-3,-72,-72,-71,-72,-71,-71,-71,-71,-3,-72,-72,-71,-71,-71,-71,-70,-70,-71,-71,-71,-71,-71,-71,-71,-70,-68,-71,-71,-71,-71,-71,-73,-71,-71,-71,-70,-69,-70,-70,-70,-73,-73,-73,-73,-73,-73,-72,2,-69,-69,-69,-68,-69,-69,-75,-70,-70,-69,-70,-69,-67,-65,-73,-72,-69,-69,-66,-68,-68,-68,-67,-65,-67,-67,-69,-63,-65,-64,-65,-64,-74,-75,-66,-63,-75,-63,-63,-63,-63,-64,-61,-65,-65,-64,-64,-63,-65,-66,-65,-65,-63,-66,-20,-75,-65,5,-58,-54,-57,-54,-58,-71,-67,-64,-57,-49,-62,-55,-61,-55,-55,-56,-58,-52,-58,-50,-51,-51,-55,-55,-55,-53,-60,-57,-54,-60,-62,-66,-67,-57,-13,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-52,-11,-10,-10,-57,-53,-53,-52,-53,-52,-52,-59,-44,-43,-42,-22,-22,-22,-63,-55,-74,-75,-62,-61,-61,-20,-63,-48,-64,-60,-34,-34,-32,-61,-62,-50,-60,-59,-61,-61,-62,-63,-63,-63,-59,-60,-57,-13,-59,-60,-59,-60,-71,-60,-60,-60,-59,-16,-58,-59,-57,-59,-58,-59,-59,-58,-59,-57,-56,-56,-56,-56,-55,-56,-58,-60,-60,-61,-57,-60,-59,-60,-59,-13,-56,-56,-56,-51,-13,-13,-56,-54,-51,-14,-21,-70,-54,-70,-54,-54,-60,-61,-46,-43,-59,-6,-1,8,9,9,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,8,9,9,9,9,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,7,7,8,8,8,3,3,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,8,8,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,6,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,8,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,4,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,8,8,8,6,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,8,8,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,6,7,7,8,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,8,8,8,9,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,2,8,8,8,8,5,3,3,3,3,3,4,7,8,8,8,6,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,8,8,6,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,2,3,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,8,8,8,5,5,5,5,5,8,8,8,8,8,5,5,8,8,5,5,5,8,8,8,8,9,9,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,2,2,2,8,8,1,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,8,8,8,7,7,8,8,8,7,7,7,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,7,7,5,5,7,7,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,6,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,8,5,3,4,3,3,3,3,3,5,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,8,8,8,4,4,4,6,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,6,5,5,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,8,9,9,8,7,9,9,9,9,9,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,7,3,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,8,3,3,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,6,6,6,6,6,6,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,6,9,4,4,4,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,3,3,3,3,3,9,9,9,9,9,7,7,7,7,8,8,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-12,-11,-12,-12,9,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-12,7,7,6,9,9,9,9,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,8,6,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,8,-11,-10,-10,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,7,-11,-10,-10,9,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,9,9,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,-10,-11,-12,-12,-11,-11,-10,-10,9,-10,-11,-10,-12,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-15,-12,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-12,-10,-10,-12,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,7,-12,-10,-12,-11,-11,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-11,-13,-10,-11,-12,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-12,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-13,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-12,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,9,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-13,-10,-11,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-12,-11,-10,-10,9,-11,-13,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-13,-10,-10,-10,-12,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-12,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-13,-13,-10,-10,-10,-13,-10,-12,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-14,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-14,-11,-12,-10,-10,-12,-10,-11,-10,-10,-13,-11,-10,-12,-10,-11,-13,-14,-10,-10,-10,-13,9,6,-10,-13,-10,-10,-14,-10,-10,-10,-10,-15,-10,-10,-15,-10,-15,-10,-15,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-15,-10,-10,-10,-13,-16,-14,4,-15,-10,-15,-15,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,7,-12,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-12,-10,-12,-11,-10,-10,9,-10,-10,-11,-10,-12,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-12,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,8,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-12,-10,-11,-10,-10,-12,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-13,-10,-10,-10,-14,-14,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-13,-12,-10,-10,-12,-10,-11,-10,-14,-11,-12,-10,-10,-12,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-14,-10,-10,-10,-11,-12,7,-14,-10,-12,-10,-15,-13,-10,-13,-14,-10,-13,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-13,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-12,-11,-11,-12,-10,-13,-11,-10,-13,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-12,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-11,-11,-11,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-14,-13,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,7,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-12,-10,-11,-10,-11,-12,-10,8,-11,-11,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-14,-10,-10,-13,-10,-13,-11,-10,-10,-10,-14,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-11,-12,-12,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-12,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-12,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,9,-12,-10,-10,-10,9,-11,-10,9,-10,-11,9,-10,-10,-13,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-13,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,9,-10,-11,-11,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-14,-13,-10,-10,-12,6,-10,-12,-14,-10,-12,-10,-10,-13,-10,-14,-10,-12,-10,-10,-13,-12,-10,-10,-10,-14,-10,-11,-10,-10,7,-13,-10,-13,-10,-10,-13,-10,-11,-10,-10,9,-11,-13,-10,-15,-13,6,-12,-10,-10,-10,-13,-13,-13,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-12,-12,-11,-10,-10,-10,9,-10,9,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,9,-10,-11,9,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,9,9,-11,-11,-12,-12,9,-10,-10,9,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-13,-13,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-13,-10,-10,-10,-10,-13,-10,-14,-10,-11,-12,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-12,-10,-11,-12,-11,-10,9,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-14,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-12,-11,-11,-10,-10,9,-12,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,9,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,9,-12,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-12,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,9,-10,-11,9,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-11,-12,-10,9,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,9,-11,-10,-12,-12,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,9,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-11,-16,-10,-10,-11,9,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,9,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,9,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,9,-10,-10,-11,-12,-11,-12,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-11,-10,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-12,-10,-11,9,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-12,-10,-13,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,9,-10,-11,-11,-12,-10,-10,-12,-11,-12,-11,-10,-10,9,8,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-12,-12,-11,-10,-10,-10,-12,-11,-12,-12,-10,-11,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-13,9,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,9,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,9,-10,-11,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,9,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-12,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-12,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-11,-12,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-12,-12,-10,-12,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,9,-11,-11,-10,-12,-11,-14,-10,9,-11,-10,-10,-12,-12,-10,-10,-12,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-13,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-12,-11,-13,-10,-12,-10,-10,9,-10,-10,-12,-11,9,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,9,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-12,-11,-12,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,9,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,9,-11,-10,-11,9,-12,-11,-10,9,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,9,9,8,8,-10,8,8,-10,-10,-12,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-12,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-12,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,9,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,9,9,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,9,-13,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,7,8,-10,-10,9,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-31,-10,-10,-11,-11,8,-10,-12,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-12,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-12,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,9,-11,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-12,-10,-11,-11,-10,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,9,-10,-10,9,-10,-11,-12,-10,-12,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,9,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-11,9,-10,-11,-13,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,9,-10,-12,-12,-10,-10,-11,-10,-12,-12,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-12,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-12,9,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-13,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-12,-11,-11,-10,-10,9,-10,-10,9,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,9,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,9,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-17,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,9,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-12,-11,-13,-10,-10,-10,-12,-13,-12,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-13,-10,-12,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-15,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-13,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-19,-10,-11,-11,-11,-11,9,-10,-12,-10,-11,-12,-10,9,-10,-10,-11,-10,-13,-11,-25,-11,-11,9,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,9,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-70,-10,-11,-12,-12,9,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-12,-11,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-11,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-12,-11,-10,-10,-11,-14,-11,-10,-10,9,9,-11,9,-11,-12,-10,-10,-10,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,9,-10,9,-12,-12,9,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-12,-12,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,9,-10,-10,9,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-12,-10,-12,-10,9,-11,-11,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,9,-10,-10,9,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,9,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-12,-11,-11,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,9,-11,-11,-10,9,-10,-10,-10,9,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-13,9,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,9,9,9,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-12,-10,-11,-10,-11,-12,-10,-11,-13,-10,-12,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-41,-10,-10,-10,-12,-11,-12,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-12,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,9,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,9,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,9,-11,9,-10,-11,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-13,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-11,-11,9,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,9,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,9,-11,-12,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,9,-10,-13,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,9,9,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-12,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,9,9,-10,9,-10,-10,-10,9,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-11,-11,9,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-12,-11,-12,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,9,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,9,-11,-11,9,-10,-12,-11,-10,-11,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-12,-12,-10,-12,-10,-10,9,9,-11,-11,9,-10,-11,-10,-10,9,-11,-11,-10,-12,-10,-12,-10,-11,-11,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,8,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-12,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,8,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-12,-11,-10,-12,-10,-10,-11,9,-12,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,9,-10,-10,9,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-12,-10,9,9,-11,-10,-10,-10,9,-10,-11,-12,-10,9,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,9,-10,-11,-12,-11,-12,-11,-11,-11,-12,-10,-12,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-12,-10,-12,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-14,-10,-10,-11,9,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-12,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,9,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-13,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,9,-12,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-13,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-12,-10,-10,9,-10,-10,-11,-11,8,-11,-11,-11,-11,-10,9,-10,-12,-11,-11,-10,-12,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-12,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,9,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,9,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-12,-10,-12,-13,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,9,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-12,-12,-11,-12,-10,-11,-12,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,9,-11,-10,-10,-11,-13,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-13,9,-10,9,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,8,9,9,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,9,-10,-10,-10,8,-10,-11,-10,-12,-13,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,9,-10,-10,-11,-10,-12,-11,-11,-10,-11,-12,-12,-11,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,9,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,9,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-12,-10,-12,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-12,-10,-12,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,9,-10,-11,-11,-10,-12,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,9,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,9,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,9,-10,9,-10,-10,-10,-12,9,9,9,-12,-10,9,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-13,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-14,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,9,-10,-10,9,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,9,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-12,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-11,-11,9,-13,-10,9,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-12,-10,-11,-10,9,-11,-11,-10,-12,9,-12,9,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-12,-12,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-11,9,-11,-12,-10,-10,-13,-11,-12,-10,-10,-12,-10,-11,9,-12,-10,-12,-11,-10,-12,-11,-10,-10,-12,-11,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,9,-11,-10,-10,-10,-12,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-11,7,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,9,-11,-11,-12,-10,9,-11,9,-10,-10,-12,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-12,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,9,9,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-12,9,-10,-10,-10,-11,-12,-12,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,9,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-33,-10,-10,-10,-10,9,-12,-10,-10,-11,-12,-10,-12,-10,-10,-51,-10,-11,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-12,9,-10,9,-10,-11,-11,-12,-15,9,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,8,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-13,-10,-14,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-41,-12,-11,-10,-10,-10,9,-12,-10,-10,9,-10,-10,-13,-10,-10,-12,-12,-12,-10,-11,-11,-12,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-12,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,9,-70,-10,-19,-10,-10,-10,-70,-69,-10,-10,-46,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-13,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,9,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-12,-12,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-11,-11,-11,-11,-10,-12,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,9,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-13,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,9,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,9,9,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-12,-10,-11,-12,-10,-11,-11,-11,9,-10,-10,-10,-13,-31,8,-12,-10,-10,9,-10,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,-19,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,8,-10,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-12,-10,-12,-10,-11,-11,-35,-12,-11,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,9,9,-11,-11,-10,9,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-11,9,-10,-11,-11,9,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-34,-10,-10,-13,-10,-10,-12,-11,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,9,9,-10,-10,-11,-12,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-12,-12,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-12,-10,9,-10,-11,-67,-11,-11,-11,-11,-11,-12,-11,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,9,9,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-13,-11,-10,-11,-10,-12,9,9,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,9,-10,-12,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,9,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-15,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-10,9,-12,-13,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-11,9,-10,-11,-11,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,8,-10,-10,8,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-12,-12,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-12,-10,-10,-10,9,-10,-11,-11,9,-10,-10,-12,-10,-10,-10,-11,-11,-11,-10,9,-10,-11,-10,-11,-10,-11,-13,-10,-10,-10,-10,-11,-12,-11,-11,-10,-10,-11,-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,-12,-10,-11,9,-11,-10
```

Basically all I want is a vector with the data so I can plot it...

Comment: you can use `scan`,  `data <- scan('temp.txt', sep = ",")`

Comment: @BappaDas thanks for the suggestion but did not help.